# Division polynomial by polynomial with 2 variables

Tags: polynomials

With only one variable I am able to solve but with two variables I am not getting it $$\frac{a^6+a^5b+a^4b^2-a^2b^4}{a^3-b^3}$$

Comment: Can you provide some of your work so that we can see what's going wrong?

Comment: I am using cell phone now :( It's very limited to post here.. so I could not post what I have done

Answer (score 2):

Note that numerator and denominator are homogenous, we can write 
$$ a^6 + a^5b + a^4b^2 -a^2b^4 = \frac 1{b^6}\left( \frac{a^6}{b^6} + \frac{a^5}{b^5} + \frac{a^4}{b^4} - \frac{a^2}{b^2} \right) $$
and 
$$ a^3 - b^3 = \frac{1}{b^3} \left( \frac{a^3}{b^3} - 1 \right) $$
Hence both can be written as polynomials in $\frac ab$, now divide as usual.